# SendHeaderErr for https requests in okhttp

Tags: okhttp

```
public synchronized BaseHttpClient exec() throws IOException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("URL-Request: {}", url);
    onBeforeExec();
    Response result = client.newCall(request.build()).execute();
    response = result;
    log.info("URL-Requested in {} ms, {}", System.currentTimeMillis() - start, url);
    return this;
}
```

---

java.lang.NullPointerException

at okio.OutputStreamSink.write(JvmOkio.kt:51)

at okio.AsyncTimeout$sink$1.write(AsyncTimeout.kt:103)

at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.kt:255)

at okio.RealBufferedSink.writeByte(RealBufferedSink.kt:210)

at okhttp3.internal.Util.writeMedium(Util.kt:317)

at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer.frameHeader(Http2Writer.kt:261)

at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer.headers(Http2Writer.kt:302)

at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.newStream(Http2Connection.kt:259)

at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.newStream(Http2Connection.kt:225)

at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.writeRequestHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:76)

at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.writeRequestHeaders(Exchange.kt:59)

at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:36)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)

at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)

at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)

at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)

at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.okhttp.v3_0.TracingInterceptor.intercept(TracingInterceptor.java:44)

at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)

at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)

at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)

at com.nx.saasplat.base.common.utils.BaseHttpClient.exec(BaseHttpClient.java:445)